# Acer 5750G-2334G75Mnkk Switchable graphics option in BIOS

Tags: nvidia, bios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

Ive recently bought this new laptop Acer 5750G and im having issues using the nvidia card on ubuntu.

System specs are:

- Processor:Intel® Core i3 2330M
- Chipset: Mobile Intel® HM65 Express
- Graphic Card: nVidia GeForce GT 520M
- Ram: 4Gb

I was trying to install ubuntu 11.10 and installation hanged on a phase were it was checking
[sda] Attached SCSI removable disk

So i searched on the internet and i finally did a succesfull install by modifying BIOS graphic mode from switchable to integrated graphic.

All in all, ubuntu 11.10 works perfectly fine if i select integrated on my BIOS but if i select switchable on the BIOS ubuntu just hangs on boot, i would like to use my nvidia card on ubuntu and atm im not finding any solution to my problem.
Also may be related my laptop integrates NVIDIA OPTIMUS Technology.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate and unfortunately your hardware is incompatible.